# Problem with for loop in a to-do website - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I have a problem with creating a for loop that will remove all my to-do lists. I've been coding for a week so this might sound like a really stupid question. The code is all in a function and is run by a buttons onclick attribute.

```
    let toDoList = document.querySelector(".to-do-list");
    let newListClass = document.getElementsByClassName('new-list');
    let newList = document.querySelector('.new-list');

    console.log(newList);
    console.log(newListClass.length);
    
    for (i = 0; i < newListClass.length; i++) {
        newList.remove();
    }
```

Comment: Hi! So.. what is the problem with it? Do you get an error? Also, what are you exactly trying to do? Your loop doesn't really make sense because `newList` is always only a single element meaning you can only remove it once.

Comment: It only removes one of the lists but I do not know how to loop so all new lists I created get removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two main options that I see:

```
// Option A) getting elements by class name
const newListClass = document.getElementsByClassName('new-list');
console.log(newListClass);

for (i = 0; i < newListClass.length; i++) {
    newListClass[i].remove();
}

// Option B) getting elements with a selector, notice the "All"
const newListClass = document.querySelectorAll('.new-list');
console.log(newListClass);

for (i = 0; i < newListClass.length; i++) {
    newListClass[i].remove();
}
```

You could also use forEach, but a classic for loop is always good